# Unable to create a constant value of type, Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq

In this line of code I got this error "Unable to create a constant value of type, 'Repository.DB.Item' Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

```
result = _itemRepository.All().Where(i => result.Any(r => i.ID != r.ID)).ToList();
```

did I miss something?

Comment: What is `All` doing here? What is `result`? What is `_itemRepository`? Help us to help you!

Comment: try put `result.Any(r => i.ID != r.ID)`into local variable before this line.

Comment: @DavidG, this is for result:  List<Repository.DB.Item> result = new List<Item>(); it's db item. and _itemRepository is IRepository<item>

Comment: you cant have `All()` with zero arguments. this is wrong. also `All` returns bool. so `Where` after `All` is wrong too.

Comment: ok, any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have missed something too. Where you say result.Any(r => i.ID != r.ID) do you already have an instance of result? It looks (to me) like you are trying to evaluate a condition on the result resultset before you have evaluated what resultset result is. Not sure if this helps you at all though.

Sorry I can't use comment yet so having to use answer.

Is what you are trying to achieve is that result will be a list of all repository items which do not appear on the previous result list?

If so, then instead, why not just reverse the logic that made the first result  list and put it into result2. You would then have result (original list) and result2 (second list) where the two lists together would give you all items in the repository.

Comment: yes there is already an instance of result